# Azure Network Security Group - Inbound - Ports Not working

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, ubuntu-14.04, azure-networking

Created a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM in Azure Resource Management Group (ARM). Added few ports to Inbound security rules (for example 9220, 6789, 6980), out of these ports, only 9220 (along with default enabled ports - 22, 80) is working and all other ports are not working. NSG is perfectly associated with the NIC & subnet, no luck and even created a new NSG & associated with same NIC & subnet, still no luck. Ubuntu Firewall is disabled by default.[Screenshot of NSG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPKoU.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it seems that your service is not listening or listening on `127.0.0.1`.

You could use `netstat -ant|grep <port>`. The result should be like below:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:<port>              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

The service could not listen on 127.0.0.1. It should be listening on `0.0.0.0` or VM private IP(such as 10.0.0.4).

You could check inside your VM, `curl 127.0.0.1:<port>`. Please ensure it could provide service.

Comment: Hi @Walter - MSFT, Yes you are right, it is listening to 127.0.0.1. Where should I change this? Connecting ports (9220) is listening at 0.0.0.0

Comment: @MuruganDurai It depends on your service. You could search it on google.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your VM network card, select Effective Security Rules and check what's in there, just to make sure your rules are applied. After that, check your Linux box for open ports

```
netstat -tulnp | grep <port no>
```