# Azure - Allow incoming traffic on specific port

Tags: azure, port, ubuntu-18.04, web-applications, azure-networking

I am running a NodeJS app on port 5000 on an Ubuntu 18.04 VM on Azure and I need external access to that app.
I created the inbound and outbound rules and double checked the settings based on this guide https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal but so far I am unable to access the app using my public ip and port.

[image]

Is there anything else I should look for? Most guides I found suggest adding outbound and inbound rules.
I also checked the firewall in Ubuntu it's disabled by default.

Found this post as well ([Azure Network Security Group - Inbound - Ports Not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/859813/azure-network-security-group-inbound-ports-not-working)).
Running `netstat -ant|grep 5000`shows this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You programmed your app to only listen for connections on the local host. Our sister site [so] can help you with fixing your program.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Thanks. That solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Those rules are on the Network security group (NSG). Make sure that the NSG is attached to either the subnet or the nic (or both).

Also, make sure that you have the ports open on the operating system as well.